# How can I get the uuid of estimote beacon using android beacon library?

Tags: android, altbeacon, estimote

I am able to detect estimote beacons using android beacon library.

But the libirary giving me the uuid of the beacon as -1.
The beacon layout I used for detecting estimote beacon is

"m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24".

Can any one help me?

Comment: Does the Estimote Android SDK (https://github.com/estimote/android-sdk) detect the UUID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

beacon.getId1() will give the uuid